# Посчитать сумму углов треугольника

Tags: python

Есть код который формирует треугольник, каким методом можно сложить  числа на углах (1, 22, 28)

```
currentNumber = 1
stop = 2
rows = 7 # Количество строк, из которых состоит пирамида
for i in range(rows):
    for column in range(1, stop):
        print(currentNumber, end=' ')
        currentNumber += 1
    print("")
    stop += 1
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сумма углов треугольника уже давно посчитана. Она всегда 180° (в евклидовой геометрии).

Comment: По левому столбику алгебраическая прогрессия

Comment: По правому собственно тоже

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если чуть покумекать, то "метод" получится простой

```
summm = rows * rows + 2
```

(подсказка: "треугольные числа")

Comment: Спасибо! формула подошла